# SVN - Batch script to do merging only if there are no conflicts

Tags: svn, batch-file, merge

I am new comer in batch scripting.
Currently I am automating some of our release process task using batch script.
In my script, I want svn to merge sourceBranch to releaseBranch only if there are no conflicts.

I tried something like this:

SET /P MergeStatus=svn merge -c39 %sourceBranchURL%

echo %MergeStatus%

But this does not work. "MergeStatus" does not get any value and svn merge too does not work in this way. My plan was to check the value of MergeStatus in case of conflicts and exit the script if conflicts are there.

Can anyone please help me in this?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

`svn merge` doesn't have any exit codes

You can always perform test-merge and check results `svn merge ... --dry-run`

No-conflict merge, according to `svn help merge`

```
For each merged item a line will be printed with characters reporting the
action taken. These characters have the following meaning:

    A  Added
    D  Deleted
    U  Updated
    C  Conflict
    G  Merged
    E  Existed
    R  Replaced

  Characters in the first column report about the item itself.
  Characters in the second column report about properties of the item.
  A 'C' in the third column indicates a tree conflict
```

must not have `C` character as merge-status, for all objects

Comment: Yes I can use --dry-run option. But how do I check the output of svn merge --dry-run command in batch script? Following is my batch script:`svn merge -c39 --dry-run %sourceBranchURL%`
`svn commit -m "Merged %sourceBranchName% to %releaseBranchName%"` The svn commit depends upon my merge --dry-run output. If there are conflicts then I want to exit from the script. Else I want to commit it. How can we do this?

Comment: @user3668231 - smth. like `svn merge --dry-run ... | grep PATTERN -q` and you have to have only smart pattern, which catch all 'C' in merge-output (-q in grep "Exit  immediately  with  **zero status if any match is found**")